# Unexpected result when falling back to a ternary operator from and OR in Javascript

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements, conditional-operator

Can anyone of you incredible and wise developers  out there tell me why

```js
"yes" || true === true ? "no" : null
```

returns `"no"`

but

```js
"yes" || (true === true ? "no" : null)
```

returns `"yes"`?

It's stumped me!

Comment: That's because of [Operator precedence in JS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence#Table). `||` _(precedence: 5)_ is executed before `.. ? .. : ..` _(precedence: 4)_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OR operator (`||`) is a short-circuit operator, so as soon as it finds a truthy value, it returns it.  In the second case, you've got two values, `"yes"`, and everything inside the parens.  Since `"yes"`, a non-empty string, is truthy, it will short circuit to return that.

In your first case, everything before the `?` is implicitly grouped together, so it's the same as saying `("yes" || true === true) ? "no" : null`.  Since `("yes" || true === true)` evaluates to truthy, we'll get the affirmative option of the ternary, `"no"`.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript will stop evaluating a conditional if it knows for certain what the value is.

The falsy values in JavaScript are 0, 0n, null, undefined, false, NaN, and the empty string ""

Since "yes" is none of those, it will always evaluate to true.

In your first example:

```
"yes" || true === true
```

Is the conditional being evaluating and is true, resulting in the ternary operation taking the true path and evaluating to "no".

In your second example

```
true === true
```

Is the conditional but is also true, resulting in the ternary operation again taking the true path and evaluating to "no"

However, when OR'ed with "yes" first, javascript stops evaluating and simply returns "yes"

Answer (score 0):

first, || (or) returns the first true value.

so here:

```
"yes" || true === true ? "no" : null
```

it will return "no" because `"yes" == true` but not ===
so it will look at the second value which is true, and `true === true`, thats right.

second one, will execute the code inside the () first
so, `(true === true ? "no" : null)` will return "no"
then `"yes" || "no"` will return `"yes"` because it first true value

Answer (score 0):

OR is meant to evaluate boolean arguments only, from left to right, until the first true value is found. If all the arguments aren't boolean but can be evaluated OR returns the first truthy value, in your case '(true === true? "no": null)' cannot be evaluated, then it returns 'yes'  because is the first value that could be evaluated.

```
let value = false || '0' || 'true';

console.log(value); //returns '0'
```

PD: Sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a way for the runtime to know if its a ternary (`?:`) or a short-circuiting logical OR (`||`)  without parentheses.  A lot of posts are correct according to the [Operator Precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence#table), `||` should take precedence over `?:`, but it may not be a question of operator precedence but rather when to apply the [short-circuit behavior](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence#short-circuiting).

I realized this when I saw `const shouldBeTrue = true || (true ? 'foo' : 'bar')` evaluates to true.  It's because short-circuiting relies on knowing the left and right operands and once you add parentheses, you have clear left and right operands and short-circuiting can take place.